# JavaScript drop-down doesn't work after page loads

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Under the "subjunctivisor" graphic on https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/ there is a drop-down box based on simple JavaScript: you choose an item and are automatically forwarded to that page.

If you click the drop-down while the page is still loading, it sometimes works. But if you wait until the page fully loads, nothing happens when you click the drop-down - you can't even make a selection.

I've looked at this with web console but don't see any obvious errors.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") { location=form.select.options[index].value;}} </SCRIPT>
<FORM NAME="form1"> <SELECT NAME="select" ONCHANGE="goto(this.form)" SIZE="1">
<option value="">Choose a verb or expression</option>
<option value="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/accepter/">accepter que</option>
<option value="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/accorder/">accorder que</option>
```

(omitted 250 other options)

```
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Your right-click blocker 1) doesn't actually prevent theft, and 2) makes it a pain to debug your site.

Comment: @isherwood Do you actually reproduce the bug? I don't... It works fine over here in Chrome 43 / Firefox 38 on Win7.

Comment: Yeah, I see it in Chrome/Win7-64. I can override as OP describes by catching it immediately on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: the Content Copy Protection & Prevent Image Save plugin had an option to disable selection. Once I unchecked that option, the js worked.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your right-click blocker has functions to disable select elements (for some strange reason). Remove it because it doesn't do you any good anyway.

Look for this function in particular (and its IE equivalent):

```
function disableselect(e) { ... }
```

It resides in an inline script tag that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true">
```

---

Update: I may have misinterpreted what that function does. It's worth a try removing it, however.

Comment: Between that and the right-click blocker, you got me on to the right path, though - it's working now, There was an option to disable select in the right-click blocker. So thank you.

Comment: No problem. However, it would be more appropriate to post and accept an accurate solution of your own to provide value to the community. Upvote my answer instead if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've posted the solution, but apparently I have to return in two days in order to accept it.